# @PersistenceContext in abstract superclass or in each concrete subclass?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Would you add the `@PersistenceContext` annotation in the abstract superclass, or would you add it in each concrete SqlRepository and then pass the reference to constructor of the superclass? Any pro/cons?

```
@Stateless
public abstract class AbstractSqlRepository<T> implements Repository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
...
```

Comment: In the base class since it is common for all. Otherwise, I will be writing the same piece of code in each subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple persistence units, you may wish to reconsider putting the entity manager in a base class. You will be coupling all your child classes to the same persistence unit.

Personally, I would define the entity manager a tier above your data tier. This will give you more control over transactions. Also, if you don't have it in a parent class, you can use different persistence units.